# I've sent 1 ETH to a contract 7 year ago - how to recover?

Tags: recover

I'm going through my different wallets at the moment to consolidate them. I've found an entry in my text file mentioning the address `0x34368337fCf63598D349b8696846EC38E3b97Fe1` and a password.
Unfortunately I have absolutely no clue how to recover that 1 eth. It was in 2017 when I was starting my crypto journey.

Can anyone please give an advice how to recover?

Thanks & Best,
Matthias

Comment: Is this your EOA address? Also, have you backed up the seed recovery phrase or do you only have the unlock password?

Answer (score 1):

That is probably a password to a metamask wallet you created.

If it is, the only way to recover the money is to open the device metamask was installed, enter the password and move the funds somewhere else.

Try to remember how the address was created (was it from an exchange / software / hardware wallet) and check if you have a seedphrase in the document.

If you cant find the source of the address you won't be able to recover the funds.

Answer (score 1):

This is a smart contract. Look here https://etherscan.io/address/0x34368337fCf63598D349b8696846EC38E3b97Fe1. There is no pass required. Unsually you will need to connect to your wallet via **Connect to Web3** and here you will need your password. Your wallet address is 0xCb99990BF360f4806F87Cf38a3b22E4Eae373a6d (contract creator). Luckily for you, the contract is verified. So, if you are the owner you can transfer your token out of the contract.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to connect to my old wallet 0xCb999... and transfer my resting ETH to my current Wallet. But how to interact with that old 1 ETH contract? I don't know how to transfer from the contract. In myetherwallet I see an option to "Interact with Contract". But what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I only see one owner `0xCb99990BF360f4806F87Cf38a3b22E4Eae373a6d`. It should be able to withdraw by calling `execute()`.